# How to make a Squarespace like social icon effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, squarespace

I'm trying to get a Squarespace like social icon effects on my project.

You may check these examples below:
http://eringreenawald.com

Look for the social icons, when you hover over an icon other icons gets transparent (or grey or something like that). Do you guys have any idea how to achieve this.

Normal view, while not hovering the cursor over a specific icon

[image]

When hovering over an icon. Here, I've placed my cursor on Twitter icon and instantly all other icons faded out to a lighter color

Comment: What have you tried yourself? please show us, this can be done easy with just pure css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").hover(function(){
        $('a').css('opacity',0.5);
        $(this).css('opacity',1);
    },function(){
        $('a').css('opacity',1);
    })
})
```

```css
a {
    color: #000;
    margin-right:5px;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking about where to get the icons, but more how to make the hover effect on the page

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS you can do as follows:

```css
ul:hover li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul:hover li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: here is bug, When you hover on ul (before li s) all items get opacity:0.5.

Comment: @ehsan The Squarespace icons referenced by OP have this same behaviour.